# Should I use vector or set in my special situation? Or something entirely different?

Tags: c++, sorting, boost, stl, containers

So, I've spent many hours reading various questions, blog posts, articles, etc. about performance comparisons of different STL containers in different situations.

However, I was not yet able to find a good source for **my exact situation** (3D game):

I am collecting a large number (definitely more than 5k, likely below 50k) of pointers to some class (it's exact nature is not relevant I think) and want to sort them by a single float value which determines their distance to some arbitrary position (which does not change during the frame).

After that, I want to iterate over each stored pointer. The order is important here, hence the sorting.

Here is the situation in pseudocode:

```
// A: Insertion
foreach (class instance that needs sorting):
    container.insert( pair(distanceOfInstance, instance) );

// B: Sorting - using the distanceOfInstance as the determining factor
container.sort();

// C: Iteration in sorted order
foreach (pair in container)
    doSomethingWith(pair.instance);
```

This whole process is (potentially) repeated each frame in the game, so the optimal performance here is kinda important. The container must be cleared before **A** each time. After **C**, nothing else is done with it.

**What I do NOT (I repeat, NOT) need:**

- Random access to the container.
- The ability to insert new elements after the container has been sorted.

Currently, what I figured would be fastest is either using a vector or a set. But I don't know if - in my situation - it would be faster to insert the elements into the vector, then sort it, then iterate over each element once. Or if it would be faster to insert the elements into a set (thus sorting them during the insertion) and then iterating over each element once.

We're also using boost in our project for some other tasks, so if anyone knows a better solution inside boost (or something else entirely), I'm very open for suggestions. Also, sorry if this question has already been answered and I just didn't find it :)

Comment: How about [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)? Otherwise, with `std::set` you don't have to do the sorting as the values will be sorted on insertion. Also, remember that if you know beforehand (i.e. at point "A") the number of items to add, you can use [`reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) to eliminate the reallocations needed by a `std::vector`.

Comment: Depends what needs to be faster: the insertions or the iteration? Best bet, try both and time realistic tests.

Comment: I've read in many articles that list is really bad for sorting over large numbers of small elements. And worse for itearion as elements are not stored in order.

Comment: Do you know ahead of time with each "pass" how many items you will be processing for that go-around? If so, a vector is likely your target, reserved in size, and inserted object emplaced (word purposely chosen) before the sort. sub 50k the sort should be fast enough and the iteration will obviously be ideal. Either way, you need to bench this.

Comment: You might also want to look into (and benchmark) other [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) (such as [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque)).

Comment: I know the number of elements (not 100% exact, but it would suffice), yes, so reserving the vector is possible.

Comment: I do not see any demand for random access?

Comment: I really need to make the NOT clearer :D

Comment: Is the number of elements the same in each iteration? Or is the maximum number over all iterations known (you said _likely_ below 50K)? If yes, allocating a vector just once can save you A LOT of time. I could write you an example code for that, if so.

Comment: No, the number of elements varies in each iteration. Unfortunately :)

Comment: Ok, but you could still handle this case. I will formulate an answer...

Comment: An idea on how you could improve further: it may be that you don't need to sort *all* the elements? Maybe you only need to have the elements up to a certain distance in sorted order, or only the first `n` elements. Consider whether `std::partial_sort` or `std::nth_element` may be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by other answers, a vector should be used in your situation. Regarding time-complexity, sorting a vector takes time *O(n log n)* where *n* is the number of elements you insert. For `std::set`, the already sorted sequence comes at the cost of *O(log n)* for every single insertion. Inserting *n* elements results in *O(n log n)* running time as well. But the vector solution will be faster due to better memory locality (in short, it is stored in one contiguous memory range, which can be read and written fast).

Furthermore, `std::vector` has only constant space overhead, while `std::set` has linear overhead (it is typically implemented as [Rb-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree)).

If you have many iterations and *n* is a large number, avoid to allocate the vector's memory in every iteration. So instead of

```
while (true) {
  vector<YourClass*> container;
  container.reserve(numInstancesInCurrentIteration);
  // your code, insertions with 'container.emplace_back(...)'
}
```

do something similar to this:

```
vector<pair<float, YourClass*> > container;
while (true) {
  if (container.size() < numInstancesInCurrentIteration)
    container.resize(numInstances, pair<float, YourClass*>(-1.f, NULL));

  // A: Insert using assignments
  size_t pos = 0;
  foreach (class instance that needs sorting):  // pseudo-code
    container[pos++] = make_pair(distanceOfInstance, &instance);

  // B: Sort only the used range
  std::sort(container.begin(), container.begin() + pos);

  // C: Iterate over pointers sorted by distance
  for (auto it = container.begin(); it != container.begin() + pos; ++it)
    doSomethingWith(it->second);
}
```

After some iterations the calls to `container.resize()` will become very rare. The calls of `doSomethingWith(YourClass*)` will probably become the most expensive part of your program.

Comment: Good answer! This is more or less how I implemented in the end and the speedup was significant.

Answer (score 2):

Vectors are almost always faster in practice; if you don't need to interleave updates with lookups, then there's **no reason**<sup>1</sup> to use a `set`.

That said, you can also take a look at Google's [B-tree](https://code.google.com/p/cpp-btree/) implementation, which should be faster than set.

---

<sup>1</sup> *That is, unless you're also checking for and removing duplicates, **and** there are **many** duplicates.

(This is not common.)*

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to sort elements once I think if you use vector you will get better performance. You may also consider using a list, though I think it again will be slightly slower than a vector.

Comment: yeah I missed the not

Answer (score 1):

Performance is always tricky: you should implement it both ways and measure which one gives better output.

That said, I think vector would be a better bet, if you reserve enough elements at creation: if you use set, the newly inserted element will be sorted into the set at every insertion.  With vector you will incur that cost at one time only.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else answered I would also go with vector. It is simpler and gives more access on the memory layout of your objects.